# Fiddler - Replay but different base URL

Tags: fiddler

If I have many requests that I'd like to replay, is there a way to replay them all at once but with a different base URL/host?  Specifically, I would want to change the URL/host all at once rather than per request.  It seems the Replay and Edit only supports individual edits.